# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider

Tags: maven

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
In my pom.xml  dependency for ecahce is like below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but still i am facing the problem classNotFound Exception

Please help me out iam trying this out from past 2 days

Comment: The class you are missing is in a package `org.hibernate`, so it should come from Hibernate, no with EhCahe. (Although I imagine it would also depend on EhCache) What dependencies from hibernate have you included?

Comment: This is the list of hibernate Maven artifacts: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-obtain.html#hibernate-gsg-setup-mavenRepoArtifacts

Answer (score 6):

The dependency you're looking for is the following I think (Perhaps a different version)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I searched for the missing class using Maven Central's search site:

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider%22

Comment: For anyone who is confused why newer `hibernate-ehcache` 4.x.x artifacts don't contain `org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider`: In "newer" Hibernate versions, the configuration parameters have changed... in 4.x.x versions, it's correct to use the following: `jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");`

Comment: Also some times the value of the below property needs to be changed to                                                                                                      <property name="cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</property> in the hibernate.cfg.xml i.e. after adding the above dependency of ehcache.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this problem, it was because I was trying to update the version of hibernate.  When moving from hibernate 3.2 to 3.3, the packages split.  I had tried to replace hibernate with hibernate-core.  Reverting back to the full hibernate package (at 3.2 level) fixed my problem.

During my next round of updates, I will probably need to replace the full hibernate package with hibernate-core and hibernate-ehcache as referenced above.